# Terraform backend configuration failing

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So I am trying to execute terraform init with a customer backend configuration. But I keep getting below error message.

I tried googling it with no success. Any thoughts on the possible reason why the error below?

Here is what I run:

```
   terraform init -backend-config="key=dev/dev01/network" -backend-config="bucket=st-cf-dev" -backend-config="region=us-gov-west-1"
```

Error message:

```
Error configuring the backend "s3": error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Post https://sts.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/: net/http: invalid header field value
```

Notes:
1- the aws acccess key has full permission
2- I am using S3 as a backend for my terraform

Answer (score 1):

The issue was a white space at the end of the environment variable.

for this one:
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

But check for $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as well!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily a backend configuration issue but a credentials issue.

How do you have your credentials defined? Static credentials can be provided as:

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-gov-west-1"
  access_key = "your-access-key"
  secret_key = "your-secret-key"
}
```

Comment: So I have the environment variables to store the AWS credentials. And I did an echo to see the values of those variables. They show the correct access and secret key for AWS access.